# Xbox 360 does not recognise the internal hardrive after overwriting it with the Linux "dd" command

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

I cleaned the Xbox 360 internal hard drive with the Linux "dd" command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc
```

After this the drive is no longer recognised by the Xbox 360 (the drive doesn't show up in System->Storage Devices).

Is there anything I can do to make the drive usable with Xbox 360 again?

I have tried to create an exFAT partition on it but it did not help.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I'm not sure if this should be tagged with [tag:homebrew] or not, but it certainly doesn't sound like a normal Xbox 360 thing...

Comment: Just tried to empty the hard drive before giving the device to someone else. Maybe a bit harsh way, but anyway, would like it back :)

Comment: This is a poweruser action but certainly not homebrew

Comment: You've wiped the entire disk including the partition table. You need to re-partition it to what the XBox is expecting, but I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you need to partition and initialize the drive with certain predefined Xbox 360-specific FATX volumes. That's how you do it on the original Xbox.

https://fatxplorer.eaton-works.com/

I use FatXplorer for original Xbox drives myself, but it seems to be mainly made for the 360. It should be able to initialize the drive for you.